# Downloaded a repo from GitHub and I need to input something to a opt/data folder and cant find it

Tags: python, github

I'm new to this sorta stuff and can't really figure out how to solve this. I've tried searching online but can't seem to find anything please help.

[So I downloaded a repo](https://github.com/ilcardella/TradingBot/blob/68ed5fd03baeea6fcfb67f9bf4601852b9003b28/README.md) and it wants me to copy a file to a "/opt/TradingBot/data" folder. For the life of me, I can't find where this opt/ folder is. At first, I thought it was the directory so I added another data folder but the script still isn't running properly. Please help.

Comment: are you on windows?

Comment: Inspect [/config/config.json](https://github.com/ilcardella/TradingBot/blob/68ed5fd03baeea6fcfb67f9bf4601852b9003b28/config/config.json) in your cloned repo - it has all the settings and references /opt/... in various places.

Comment: @Patrick Artner yes im on windows.

Answer (score 1):

you may find clarity in reading https://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/opt.html

> This directory is reserved for all the software and add-on packages that are not part of the default installation. For example, StarOffice, Kylix, Netscape Communicator and WordPerfect packages are normally found here. To comply with the FSSTND, all third party applications should be installed in this directory. Any package to be installed here must locate its static files (ie. extra fonts, clipart, database files) must locate its static files in a separate /opt/'package' or /opt/'provider' directory tree (similar to the way in which Windows will install new software to its own directory tree C:\Windows\Progam Files\"Program Name"), where 'package' is a name that describes the software package and 'provider' is the provider's LANANA registered name.

Comment: Did a second after I posted it and realized I had forgotten it :-)

Comment: do you have any idea how i can apply this knowledge to fix my problem apart from installing Linux?

Comment: The readme file includes info on running it in a Docker container (Dockerfile is included in repository). 

You can run TradingBot in a Docker container (https://docs.docker.com/).
The Docker image is configured with a default TradingBot configuration and it
does not have any `.credentials` files.